# Change user-agent in mac webview

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

Morning,

I would like to change user-agent in my first mac app but I don't know how. I tried to find sample code for mac but everything is for iOS like this:

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Your user agent", @"UserAgent", nil];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:dictionary];
```

How I can change this code to compatible with mac app?
Any ideas will be great for me :-)

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted will simply add the user agent into the user defaults dictionary it won't actually change any of your requests.

`NSMutableURLRequest` has a method `setValue:forHTTPHeaderField`. So you can do

```
[yourRequest setValue:@"MyCoolUserAgentString" forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];
```

If you're storing the user agent in `NSUserDefaults` you could do this

```
[yourRequest setValue:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"UserAgent"] forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];
```

Comment: Well @Jamie I have this:
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://XYZ"]];
 [self.webView.mainFrame loadRequest:request];

How I can do to make it work?

Comment: NSMutableURLRequest is a subclass of NSURLRequest therefore you can simply replace NSURLRequest with NSMutableURLRequest

Comment: OK, well I have     NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://whatsmyuseragent.com"];
    NSMutableURLRequest* request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
    [request setValue:@"MyCoolUserAgentString" forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"]; and its still doesn't work. What I done wrong?